# Is that called Police Traffic Stop?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

How do you call when police cars block every lane of a given street, except one, and force all cars to funnel through that single lane, in order to pass in front of a line of cops, that are looking for someone or stopping drivers at random?

It that called 'police traffic stop'? I am guessing the term based on what it would be called in my own language.

Comment: I would call it a “police checkpoint”.

Comment: a police traffic stop is not right. The police direct traffic to use a single lane. Traffic break https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_break

Comment: @StephenS - brilliant. Can you make it an answer?

Comment: "Police roadblock" is the only phrase that sprang to mind, but that might suggest that the road was blocked off completely.  I like StephenS's answer, "police checkpoint".  I don't think the term "traffic break" is used in the UK (but it may be a valid answer for the US, of course).

Comment: Traffic break is used, but for something else: holding traffic back so the road can be cleared of a hazard. A traffic break can be implemented as a roadblock, or a rolling roadblock, but there is no checking of cars in a traffic break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Police checkpoint" would seem to be the best expression.

The closing of lanes and forcing cars to stop is called a "roadblock".  The purpose of the roadblock is to allow police to run a checkpoint.

(a traffic break is something else, see the relevant wikipage)